# Forward HTTP request to an external server, using static IP - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, aws-nat-gateway

I'm trying to forward a HTTP request to an external server using API Gateway. This external server is whitelisting IPs, such as the one allocated to a NAT Gateway we have.

If I just create an API Gateway HTTP, it wil work the way I want, but it will dynamic choose outbound IPs from cloudfare. Now, I wanted to route this outbound traffic from my API Gateway so it can use, for example, my NAT Gateway, or some other elastic IP that I can send to people whitelist it as well.

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: You can proxy through lambda in vpc.

Comment: @Marcin I will have to create a lambda function to read the entire request, just to make it again in another url? Sorry, I'm a begginner

Comment: Yes. You would have to place lambda in private subnet of your VPC, so that your requests from lambda go through NAT.